# Swift - speed and efficiency of higher order functions (reduce)

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, performance

Quick question please about the efficiency of higher order swift functions with large input data. During a recent test I had a question about finding 'equlibirum indexes' in arrays- i.e. the index of an array where the sum of all elements below the index equals the sum of all elements above the index

> An equilibrium index of this array is any integer P such that 0 ≤ P <
> N and the sum of elements of lower indices is equal to the sum of
> elements of higher indices, i.e.
>
> ```
>           A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[P−1] = A[P+1] + ... + A[N−2] + A[N−1].
> ```

The challenge was to write a short function which computed the first (or any) index which was considered 'equilibirum'.
I put together a simple snippet which scored highly but failed some of the 'performance' tests which used large input data (array sizes around 100,000).

Here's the code

```
public func solution(inout A : [Int]) -> Int {
   var index = 0;
        for _ in A {
            let sumBefore = A[0...index].reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
            let sumAfter = A[index...A.count-1].reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
            if (sumBefore == sumAfter) { return index; }
            index += 1;
        }
        return -1;
}
```

Would anyone please be able to explain why the code performs so poorly with large sets of data, or any recommended alternatives?

Here, for example is a description of a failing perfomance test:

> Large performance test, O(n^2) solutions should fail.
>
> ✘ TIMEOUT ERROR
> running time: >6.00 sec., time limit: 0.22 sec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the challenge is failing because your solution is `O(n^2)`.

Your `for` loop, along with 2 sequential `reduce`s inside, make your solution ~ `O(2*n^2)` since `reduce` goes through all the elements again.

A simpler solution is to first compute the whole sum, and then iterate through the elements once, subtracting each value from the whole sum, one by one, thus having access to the left and right sums, for comparison.

Using Swift 3.0, Xcode 8:

```
func findEquilibriumIndex(in array: [Int]) -> Int? {
  var leftSum = 0
  var rightSum = array.reduce(0, combine: +)


  for (index, value) in array.enumerated() {
    rightSum -= value

    if leftSum == rightSum {
        return index
    }

    leftSum += value
  }

  return nil
}

let sampleArray = [-7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0]

findEquilibriumIndex(in: sampleArray)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not that "the built-in functions perform so poorly."
Your solution is slow because in each iteration, `N` elements are
added (`N` being the length of the array). It would be more efficient
to compute the total sum *once* and update the "before sum"
and "after sum" while traversing through the array. This reduces
the complexity from `O(N^2)` to `O(N)`:

```
public func solution(A : [Int]) -> Int {

    var sumBefore = 0
    var sumAfter = A.reduce(0, combine: +)

    for (idx, elem) in A.enumerate() {
        sumAfter -= elem
        if sumBefore == sumAfter {
            return idx
        }
        sumBefore += elem
    }
    return -1
}
```

(Swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3.1)

*Remarks:*

- There is no reason to pass the array as `inout` parameter.
- An operator (in this case `+`) can be passed as a argument to the `reduce()` function.
- `enumerate()` returns a sequence of array indices together with
  the corresponding element, this saves another array access.

Note also that a more "Swifty" design would be to make the return type
an optional `Int?` which is `nil` if no solution was found.

Answer (score 0):

### The incrementalSums extension

If you define this extension

```
extension Array where Element : SignedInteger {
    var incrementalSums: [Element] {
        return Array(reduce([0]) { $0.0 + [$0.0.last! + $0.1] }.dropLast())
    }
}
```

given an array of `Int(s)` you can build an array where the `Int` at the `n-th` position represents the sum of the values from `0` to `(n-1)` in the original array.

Example

```
[1, 2, 3, 10, 2].incrementalSums // [0, 1, 3, 6, 16]
```

### The equilibriumIndex function

Now you can build a function like this

```
func equilibriumIndex(nums: [Int]) -> Int? {
    let leftSums = nums.incrementalSums
    let rightSums = nums.reversed().incrementalSums.reversed()
    return Array(zip(leftSums, rightSums)).index { $0 == $1 }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is a good idea to use side-effects in the closure. Most probably, it will be executed sequentially starting with the first array element, but I would not *rely* on it unless that behaviour is explicitly documented.

Comment: @MartinR: thanks for the hint. I'll try to find another way then.

Comment: @MartinR: I found another _"functional"_ solution :) Any comment would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks correct (did not test it). I *assume* that it is slower than the other suggested solutions because two arrays are built, but for a definite answer one would have to measure and compare.

Comment: @MartinR: I agree. If the solution is present, your code will usually need `n + n/2` steps. And if it is not you'll need `2n` steps. My code will usually need `2n + n/2` steps if the solution is present and `3n` steps if it is not. Your code is also probably easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional version of the solution in Swift 3

```
  let total = sampleArray.reduce(0,+) 
  var sum    = 0
  let index  = sampleArray.index{ v in defer {sum += v}; return sum * 2 == total - v }
```

If I understand correctly the element at the resulting index is excluded from the sum on each side (which I'm not certain the other solutions achieve)